# How to call GridView RowEditing with button outside the GridView?

Tags: vb.net

I have a gridview that is populated and a button outside the gridview that I want to enable editing on the selected row when clicked. I have this in the code behind. What goes in the btn_click event to invoke the grid view editing?

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEventArgs)
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    FillGrid()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnEdit_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click

    What goes here??

End Sub
```

Comment: What is stopping it from being edited in the first place? Do you have the rows marked as read only?

Comment: I'm not sure what arguments to pass to the GridView1_RowEditing from the btnClick. I don't want a column with an edit button on every row. I have a gridview with 5 columns. On the btnClick, I want 4 of the cells in the selected row to open drop down lists for editing and one to be non editable.

Comment: Just to clarify, I currently have the edit/select/delete column hidden and have added an onclick event in RowDataBound. I would like a seperate button outside the gridview that the user can click to enable editing of the selected row.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this approach.
"**GridView1_RowEditing**" is expecting a row index, so it can turn on "**EditItemTemplate**" accordingly, correct? 
But If you want to click on button outside of Gridview and make entire Gridview editable, you shouldn't trigger **GridView1_RowEditing**, since you don't know what editindex to pass.
You need to implement editable control(textbox) as part of "**ItemTemplate**", not in "**EditItemTemplate**".
And visibility of this control would be controlled by the outside button you have created, which will flag the visibility on / off.

Please review following link, this demonstrates how it should be implemented.
http://highoncoding.com/Articles/219_GridView_All_Rows_in_Edit_Mode.aspx